# 7-Zip: Get number of files in each folder within archive (without extracting)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

I have e.g. `archive.rar` which contains folders with files in it

**archive.rar**

```
\folder_a
\folder_b
\folder_c
```

How can I get number of files in each folder **(without extracting)** and export  result to a text file, e.g. (something like following)

**list.txt** (Desired result)

```
\folder_a 580
\folder_b 70
\folder_c 0
```

I have tried `7z.exe l archive.rar > list.txt` but it returns all files without indicating number of them in each folder.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you do have a list of all files with the paths you could just group them by path which would give you the number of files per path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Year's warming up: utilized the [`-slt` (Show technical information) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/list_tech.htm):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_7zArchive=%~1"
set "_7zVerbose=%~2"
if DEFINED _7zVerbose set "_7zVerbose=%_7zVerbose:-=/%" 
if NOT EXIST "%_7zArchive%" goto :Usage
REM echo Checking archive "%_7zArchive%"
echo(
set "_7zExe=c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
rem "%_7zExe%" l -slt "%_7zArchive%" | findstr /I "^Path.= ^Folder.= ^Attributes.="
set "_7zFiles=0"
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1* delims== " %%G in (`
    ^""%_7zExe%" l -slt "%_7zArchive%" ^| findstr /I "^Path.= ^Folder.="^"
`) do (
  if /I "%%~G"=="Folder" (
    set "_7zFldr=%%~H"
    call :CountFiles
  ) else (
    set "_7zPath=%%~H"
  )
)
if /I NOT "%_7zVerbose%"=="/NF" (
  echo    %_7zFiles% files in "%_7zArchive%":
  set __
)
if /I     "%_7zVerbose%"=="/NF" goto :FolderStruct
if /I NOT "%_7zVerbose%"=="/V"  goto :endlocal
:FolderStruct
echo    folder structure in "%_7zArchive%":
set $$
:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:CountFiles
  for %%g in ("H:\%_7zPath%") do (
    if "%_7zFldr%"=="-" (
      REM echo file  "%%~pg" "%%~nxg" "%%~g"
      set /A "_7zFiles+=1"
      CALL set "_7z_aux=%%__ %%~pg%%"
      set /A "_7z_aux+=1"
      CALL set "__ %%~pg=%%_7z_aux%%"
      set "$$ %%~pg= "                    # for folder structure
    ) else (
      REM echo folder "%%~pg" "%%~nxg" "%%~g"
      set "$$ %%~pnxg\= "                 # for folder structure
    )
  )
goto :eof

:Usage
echo( 
echo Get number of files in each folder within archive (without extracting^).
echo( 
echo "%~0" archive [-V^|/V ^| -NF^|/NF] [^> ^| ^>^> outfile]
echo(
echo   archive  Specifies the file to be analysed.
echo   -V, /V   Verbose: lists folder structure within archive as well.
echo   -NF,/NF  NoFiles: lists folder structure within archive only.
echo(
echo   ^> outfile   redirects output (outfile overwrite^).
echo  ^>^> outfile   redirects output (append to outfile^).
echo(
pause
goto :endlocal
```

Tested against a bunch of archives from different sources as follows (I hope that it would work for `.rar` archives as well):

```
for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /S D:\Downloads\*.zip') do @D:\bat\SU\1514106.bat "%~A"
for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /S D:\Downloads\*.zip') do @D:\bat\SU\1514106.bat "%~A" /V
for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /S D:\Downloads\*.zip') do @D:\bat\SU\1514106.bat "%~A" -NF
```

For example (of course, the ugly raw output from `set __` and `set $$` could be beautified):

```
D:\bat\SU\1514106.bat "D:\Downloads\hex-master.zip" -v
```

> ```
>    8 files in "D:\Downloads\hex-master.zip":
> __ \hex-master\=4
> __ \hex-master\build\win\=3
> __ \hex-master\src\=1
>    folder structure in "D:\Downloads\hex-master.zip":
> $$ \hex-master\=
> $$ \hex-master\build\=
> $$ \hex-master\build\win\=
> $$ \hex-master\src\=
> ```

Comment: Hi, can I ask... why not use direct (whiteout ()) in: **`') do ( /drop line/ if /I "%%~G"=="Folder" (`**  why not **`') do if /I ....(`**?

Comment: Works beautifully on the .rars that I have! Thank you so very much! And a happy new year to you too! :)

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe you are right that, in this case, the parentheses around the _single_ `if` statement could be omitted. However please keep in mind that it's most likely a residuum of debugging process. My code editor intellisense just offers parentheses after `for…do` and I keep them as (in advance) nobody knows if a single statement would suffice…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks, this is not to criticize your code, it was to learn, I thought I had a technical reason for it, to avoid future use. Thanks! Which editor do you use? The one with the intellisense code editor?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe [PSPad - text and code editor](https://www.pspad.com/en/) for the most tasks.

Comment: @JosefZ So, again, thank you!!